# New levels "cheater"?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've built three New levels but they are called "cheater" (I have the German version so it's actually "Betrüger")

I can build items there e.g. 10 tier 1 items and get gold but surely it's a bug? I definitely didn't cheat, I wouldn't even know how...

Answer (score 1):

There has been a recent phenomenon of odd names showing up in the game.  "Impostor" for dream jobs, wrong names for levels, etc.

I think that the way they are pushing out the new levels is causing some of the programmers placeholders to show up instead of the intended names.

The cure has generally been to exit the game, and reload it.  I don't know if will work in this case, but I would believe it should.